# In React, how can I traverse the entire render tree, not only "children"

Tags: reactjs

I'm interested in traversing the entire tree of components in React.

Let's say I have a component:

```
class Child extends Component {
    //...
    render() {
        return <div>
            <span>Not reachable</span>
        </div>
    }
}

class Parent extends Component {
    //...
    traverse(children) {
        console.log(children);
        React.Children.map(this.traverse);
    }
    render() {
        this.traverse(this.props.children);
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    }
}

class Container extends Component {
    //...
    render() {
        return <Parent>
            <Child />
        </Parent>
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to access the "Not reachable" span, but `React.Children.map` only traverses literally written "children", not component inner children.

Is there any way to access those in a traverse function?

Comment: What's the use case here? Seems like the hierarchy that needs to be traversed would exist in some state somewhere, not in the React elements that are created as a result of such state.

Comment: I agree with azium, tell us your use case and we might be able to help you out with an alternate solution. Generally, you do not want to traverse children like that. It is very common in libraries like jQuery, but mostly unnecessary for React.

Comment: I'm trying to create a visualization of the tree. I definitely need to be able to traverse the entire tree this way.

Comment: Please tell more about your case, maybe even include a *specific* example of what you're trying to achieve. Fwiw, you can't just do that, but if you give us more details, a more react-way could be figured.

Comment: This is as specific as I think I could get. I'm not creating a react app per se, I'm creating a tool that can crawl a react app, show a visualization and potentially other tools. So I am not looking for a specific workaround, I'm look for a general solution.

Comment: This is a good question, and the "show me your use case" comments are a bit silly. I hope somebody can actually answer this question. I'll probably hack up a quick traversal method, actually a bit shocked this doesn't exist anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to traverse the tree structure. You've done well to already find the `React.Children.map` method. It is key in going deeper.

`React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => { /* work with child */ })` affords you access to the `child` object. If the child has children, they will be accessible as `child.props.children`.

You can recursively travel through the tree structure with a recursive component. Here's an example component that simply renders the amount of children each node has.

```
const RecursiveWrapper = props => {
    const wrappedChildren = React.Children.map(
        props.children,
        child => {
            if (child.props && child.props.children) {
                return (
                    <RecursiveWrapper>
                        {child.props.children}
                    </RecursiveWrapper>
                )
            }
            return (
                <div>
                    {'children: 0'}
                </div>
            )
        }
    )
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {`children: ${wrappedChildren.length}`}
            <div>
                {wrappedChildren}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

replace each child with something more intelligible to create a visualization of the tree structure of any node wrapped in this kind of wrapper.